# How to know the path of the ascx in the Page.LoadControl?

Tags: 2010, web-part, user-controls

I have a Webpart with a "main class" named myClass

```
public class myClass : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
```

and I want to load a ascx file from this class like this

http://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&mid=34&ItemID=9&thread=3051&pagenumber=1

but when I trying to do this:

```
 Control c = Page.LoadControl("~/myAscx.ascx");
```

or

```
 Control c = Page.LoadControl("~/nameWebpart/myAscx.ascx");
```

I only get the message:

"The file myAscx.ascx does not exist"

The file myAscx is in the same "folder" of the myClass. How can I know the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place Your ascx in the layouts folder C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ and then

```
MyClass c = (MyClass)Page.LoadControl("/_layouts/MyAscx.ascx");
```

Of course You can also create a subfolder under the LAYOUTS directory and update the LoadControl path accordingly.

Comment: It works fine ^^

Answer (score 2):

ascx files are stored in the COntrolTemplates folder in the 14 hive of sharepoint.

So it's path will be something like:

```
private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/ProjectFolder/controlname.ascx";
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was a custom ascx that places in another folder. Maybe the controltemplates is only for default ascx

Comment: the _controltemplates can be substituted with whatever location under the 14 hive you want (_layouts, _vti_bin (ISAPI) etc. etc.)